# (delphi application) wrong location spotted

Tags: delphi, google-maps-api-3, delphi-xe2

i have pairs of coorinates:

```
GpsLatitude     GpsLongitude
32.012919       34.547592,
32.012798       34.54763,
32.012827       34.547584,
32.012814       34.547608,
32.01273        34.54765,
32.012868       34.547631,
32.012834       34.547577,
```

and i have show it on google map in delphi application.

i find an example [here](http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/2010/08/07/using-the-google-maps-api-v3-from-delphi-part-i-basic-functionality/) a delphi code example
and it works. But when i trying to use it with my coordinates it point
to wrong location, but when i open it in browser, like this

> "32 01.2834,34 54.7577"

it work good, unfortunatly it does not work in delphi.

what can be wrong??

Comment: I'm the author of such article and I test the code and works fine check this image http://i43.tinypic.com/jpx941.png are you sure which you are passing the right cords to the app?

Comment: [reply to RRUZ] Yes. i checked it any times. and, as i wrote above , if i pass those coordinates throw maps.google.com (search edit box) not as float number (32.012919 34.547592), but as string (32 01.2919, 34 54.7592), it locate right point on map. unfortunatlly,  latlon script work only with numbers and cannot use string with whitespace inside

Comment: BTW.. it seems , i used yours code as base for my application ;)

Answer (score 3):

if you look the `GotoLatLng` javascript function used in the [article](http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/2010/08/07/using-the-google-maps-api-v3-from-delphi-part-i-basic-functionality/),

```
function GotoLatLng(Lat, Lang) { 
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(Lat,Lang);
  map.setCenter(latlng);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: latlng, 
  map: map,
  title:Lat+","+Lang
  });
  }
```

You can see a call to the  [google.maps.LatLng()](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng) function,  and this needs to be given two numbers in decimal format. you are using a value like this `32 01.2919, 34 54.7592` which is in degrees and minutes format, so **that format must be converted to decimal** before be passed to the javascript function. Now the reason because that value works in the google maps  page is because that page internally resolves the string passed as parameter and returns a colletion of markers as result.

Comment: ok. lot of thanks for explanation, but how i can convert it to decimal format?  and,  where i can found the algorithm?

Comment: [Different degree formats: Resolutions and conversions](http://home.online.no/~sigurdhu/Deg_formats.htm)